# Rails - Should the flash messages partial go inside the layout files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, erb

I have seen layouts like this in many Rails examples on the web:

```
...
<main role="main">
  <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
  <%= yield %>
</main>
...
```

The **_messages** partial is something like this:

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <% if msg.is_a?(String) %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :class => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I took this content from the **rails_layout** gem (as seen [here](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-default-application-layout.html)), but it is a very common practice to put the partial that renders the flash messages  on the `application.html.erb` default layout file.

In this case, if you fetch content with **Ajax** and want to replace only the main part, you'll have to do something like this:

```
def my_controller_action
  # ...
  if request.xhr?
    render :layout => 'other_layout_with_flash_messages'
  end
end
```

Then include the partial with the flash messages again in this other layout, otherwise the flash messages won't show.

---

My question is: Should the flash messages go inside the layout as they are part of the content?

Additionally: What's the best options for this ajax cases? Should I create another layout?

Comment: Are you trying to return an actual layout on an xhr request? Generally you would want to return JSON which could definitely include your error messages.

Comment: I would return only the content part, as html. I would do layout: false, but that wouldn't include the flash messages. Instead I create a thin layout with the flash partial. Is that a bad practice?

Comment: I think this may an opinion-based answer but a more standard approach these days is to return JSON using ActiveModelSerializers or jbuilder then use the data to update your view. Personally I like Angular for this and never return HTML to an xhr request.

Comment: @errata did you never return html for xhr request, or shouldn't I return html for a xhr request?

Comment: I return JSON when calling an API from a JS SPA client. I know in an earlier implementation of "AJAX" in rails people were returning html and js fragments but when building out a standard RESTful API it's more common to return JSON data.